# How to compute norm at search time in Lucene 3.6?

Tags: java, lucene

I need to perform a query over a field, one time taking into account the norm and the other without affecting the score by the norm.
What i have done is indexing the field two times with two different names as follow:

- "*field*" with Field.omitNorms(false);
- "*field_noNorm*" with Field.omitNorms(true);

This solution led me to achieve my objective, but it has duplicated the dimension of the index, and now that the index size is becoming critical, i need to find a smarter solution, also affecting the query time when searching on the field without norm.

It is possibile to store a single normalized field and multiply the inverce of the norm for each field at query time to remove its effect on the final score?
And, if so, what is the fastest way to retrieve the norm of document during the search time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem reading the norm at index time with:
*searcher.getIndexReader().norms(field);*